# Python 3.11 C Module

Tags: python, python-module

I am trying to create a Python module in C, however when I load it I get the following message.

*Fatal Python error: _PyInterpreterState_GET: the function must be called with the GIL held, but the GIL is released (the current Python thread state is NULL)*

I have seen several samples, and they all work the same way. I haven't seen a sample where the GIL lock was taken. I am using Visual Studio 2022, the compilation process is working as expected, and I am using Python 3.11 to load the module.

Does anyone know what may be causing it?

My module code is:

```c
#include "pch.h"

#define PY_SSIZE_T_CLEAN
#include <Python.h>

static PyObject* BobError;

static PyObject*
bob_system(PyObject* self, PyObject* args)
{
    const char* command;
    int sts;

    if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "s", &command))
        return NULL;

    sts = system(command);

    if (sts < 0) {
        PyErr_SetString(BobError, "System command failed");
        return NULL;
    }
    return PyLong_FromLong(sts);
}

static PyMethodDef BobMethods[] = {
    {"system",  bob_system, METH_VARARGS, "Execute a shell command."},  
    {NULL, NULL, 0, NULL}
};

static struct PyModuleDef BobModule = {
        PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT,
        "bob",
        NULL,
        -1,
        BobMethods,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        NULL
};

PyMODINIT_FUNC
PyInit_bob(void)
{
    PyObject* m = NULL;

    m = PyModule_Create(&BobModule);

    if (m == NULL)
        return NULL;

    BobError = PyErr_NewException("bob.error", NULL, NULL);

    Py_XINCREF(BobError);

    if (PyModule_AddObject(m, "error", BobError) < 0) {
        Py_XDECREF(BobError);
        Py_CLEAR(BobError);
        Py_DECREF(m);
        return NULL;
    }

    return m;
}
```

Comment: please include what you do with the code: how you compile it and how you import it.

Comment: If you are following a guide and see your results seemingly deviate from what the guide says, it may be helpful to link the guide.